# Visual C++: нарушение доступа для чтения. ce было 0xFDFDFDFD

Tags: c++, visual-c++, разработка-игр, sfml, box2d

```
for (b2ContactEdge* ce = playerBody->GetContactList(); ce; ce = ce->next) {
    b2Contact* c = ce->contact; 
    for (int i = 0; i < coinBody.size(); i++) {
        if (c->GetFixtureA() == coinBody[i]->GetFixtureList())
        {
            coinBody[i]->DestroyFixture(coinBody[i]->GetFixtureList()); 
            coin.erase(coin.begin() + i);
            coinBody.erase(coinBody.begin() + i);
        }
    }
 }
```

`coin` и `coinBody` - это вектора:

```
std::vector<Object> coin;
std::vector<b2Body*> coinBody;
```

(Object из SFML, b2Body из Box2D)

Смысл программы. Создаю платформер по статье на Хабре, эта часть кода должна обрабатывать столкновение игрока с монеткой, при столкновение фигура принадлежащая телу монетки должна уничтожаться, а потом убираться object и b2Body переменные относящиеся к этой монетке из соответствующих векторов
Проблема в том, что вот эта строчка:

```
coinBody[i]->DestroyFixture(coinBody[i]->GetFixtureList());
```

Вызывает ошибку при работе программы:

> нарушение доступа для чтения 0xFDFDFDFD

Код взят из статьи на Хабре "Создаем платформер за 30 минут", если не удалять фигуру, а сразу уменьшать вектора, то программа не вылетает, но взаимодействие происходит некорректное.

Comment: У вас расстрел памяти. http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html#table